# Navigation2D get_simple_path returns PoolVector2Array size: 0

Tags: godot, gdscript

Here's the original code:

```
var navigation = Navigation2D.new()
for door_loc in all_door_coords:
    var start_door = door_loc
    var end_door = all_door_coords[randi() % all_door_coords.size()]
    if start_door == end_door:
        continue
    var path = navigation.get_simple_path(start_door, end_door, false)
    for coord in path:
        tilemap.set_cellv(coord, -1)
```

What it does: from all the possible coordinates pick 2 and draw a nav path between them (get all the coordinates for the path). Then on each path coordinate remove the tile that is there / delete it. And so forth for each of the possible coordinates.

I use a generated tilemap, so I thought the problem is in the coordinates (local/global). Below I implemented coordinates conversion **map** -> **global** -> **local** and one for the other way around.

```
var navigation = Navigation2D.new()
for door_loc in all_door_coords:
    var start_door = to_local(tilemap.map_to_world(door_loc))
    var end_door = to_local(tilemap.map_to_world(all_door_coords[randi() % all_door_coords.size()]))
    if start_door == end_door:
        continue
    var path = navigation.get_simple_path(start_door, end_door, false)
    for coord in path:
        coord = tilemap.world_to_map(to_global(coord))
        tilemap.set_cellv(coord, -1)
```

The problem is that no matter what, I get a 0 size path coordinates array. I have also drawn nav polygons for each tile in the tileset I want to be used for this path. + I tried switching the optimization in `get_simple_path`, still nothing.

Why does it not work?

**EDIT 1**
Changed the conversion to **map** -> **local** (Thank you @Theraot)

```
var navigation = Navigation2D.new()
for door_loc in all_door_coords:
    var start_door = tilemap.map_to_world(door_loc)
    var end_door = tilemap.map_to_world(all_door_coords[randi() % all_door_coords.size()])
    if start_door == end_door:
        continue
    var path = navigation.get_simple_path(start_door, end_door, true)
    for coord in path:
        coord = tilemap.world_to_map(coord)
        tilemap.set_cellv(coord, -1)
```

They better change the names to `map_to_local` and `local_to_map`. But the problem is still there.

**EDIT 2**
Code for nav polygon creation for each tile in the generation loop:

```
var polygon = NavigationPolygon.new()
var outline = PoolVector2Array([Vector2(x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE), 
                                        Vector2(x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE+TILE_SIZE), 
                                        Vector2(x*TILE_SIZE+TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE+TILE_SIZE), 
                                        Vector2(x*TILE_SIZE+TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE)])
polygon.add_outline(outline)
polygon.make_polygons_from_outlines()
var polygon_instance = NavigationPolygonInstance.new()   #If I create an instance for each tile and then use it for .navpoly - nav polygons won't be created
$NavigationPolygonInstance.navpoly = polygon    #So I can only use preassigned node for it, that is why only one tile shows to have this polygon I suppose
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you are not getting points in the path. At least, I can tell you that you are using `world_to_map` and `map_to_world` wrong. You want to give `world_to_map` local coordinates of the `TileMap`, not global coordinates. Similarly `map_to_world` gives you local coordinates of the `TileMap`. *Yes, the names are confusing.*

Comment: @Theraot, apparently I have found the issue. The Navigation polygons I have drawn for the tiles in the tileset for the tilemap do not translate when I use the tiles in random generation (for map creation). With the debug option enabled I can't see the nav squares, only the collision ones for walls. I tried adding a nav polygon to each tile when generating them [using add_polygons](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_navigationpolygon.html). I'll update the question with it. But now only one tile is displaying to have a nav polygon, the very last one

Comment: @Theraot, I think I have found a solution to polygons not showing. I had to put a separate Navigation2D Node as a parent to my TileMap Node for the nav polygons to work properly. Still pondering on ```get_simple_path``` problem

Comment: Please don't add 'solved' or similar words to the title. Instead accept the best answer (if any) by clicking on the checkmark left of the answer. In case of your own answer, you can do it after 48 hours.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has this problem (when you generate world with a script and add Nav2D stuff to it), before calculating the path with `get_simple_path` - use `yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")` AND put your `get_simple_path` into another function or block of code, just separate it from the main code somehow. I did just that and it works perfectly. I got the solution from [this thread](https://godotengine.org/qa/72198/get_simple_path-fast-after-procedurally-generated-tilemap).

Comment: Thanks, this solved issues with Godot 3.5.2


CODE:

LINE 1:
yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
LINE 2:
path = navigation.get_simple_path(position, new_destination.position, false)

Answer (score 0):

```
yield(get_tree(), "idle_frame")
path = navigation.get_simple_path(position, new_destination.position, false)
```